# How to yield a db connection in a python sqlalchemy function similar to how it is done in FastAPI?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, yield

In FastAPI I had the following function that I used to open and close a DB session:

```py
def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

And within the routes of my API I would do something like that:

```
@router.get("/")
async def read_all_events(user: dict = Depends(get_current_user), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    logger.info("API read_all_events")
    if user is None:
        raise http_user_credentials_not_valid_exception()
    return db.query(models.Events).all()
```

You can see that I am injectin the session in the api call.

So now i want to do something similar within a python function:

```
def do_something():
   #get person data from database
   #play with person data
   #save new person data in database
   #get cars data from database
```

So i am wondering if I should use the same approach than in FastAPI (i do not know how) or if i just should be openning and clossing the connection manually like that:

```
def do_something():
   try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
 
        #get person data from database
        #play with person data
        #save new person data in database
        #get cars data from database
   finally:
        db.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of yield in this case is so that `Depends(get_db)` returns the db session instance, so that it can be used in the fastapi route, and as soon as the fastapi route returns response to user, the finally clause (`db.close()`) will be executed. This is good because every request will be using a separate db session, and db connections will be closed after every route response.

If you want to use the db session normally in a function, just get the db instance using `db = SessionLocal()`, and proceed to use the db instance in the function.

Example:

```
def do_something():
    db = SessionLocal()
    event = db.query(models.Events).first()
    db.delete(event)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```